# Python Extract Data from CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose we have a sample data below

[image]

I want to use Python and extra data from the 5th line (that is Deal ID, Deal Name, Origination Date, Maturity Date) to the 8th line. Also once I have extracted data I want to save the file in the following format ExtensionReport202205.csv and whole things should be Dynamic. I used skip rows and iloc to get rows but it is not dynamic? So kindly advise.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

My actual table:

Error Message Pic:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8XNx.jpg

Comment: Can you include the piece of code you have already developed?

Comment: What does the actual input file look like?  CSV or a text file that looks kind of what is represented in the image?  Or is this what the DF looks like and you want help from there?

Comment: "import pandas as pd  df=pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\punk\\Downloads\\sample.xlsx",skiprows=4) df2=df.iloc[0:]    "   Using this code I am able to extract the data along with the header but it is not dynamic. The above image is an excel file called sample and I want to extra data along with header and save file in csv format. I should save file as "Extension_Report202205

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.  Though you may have to tweak if you have additional requirements.

Read the XLSX:

```
xls = r'D:\jchtempnew\SO\so_fix.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(xls)
print(df)

              Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1           Unnamed: 2           Unnamed: 3
0                    NaN        NaN                  NaN                  NaN
1                    NaN        NaN                  NaN                  NaN
2    Run Date:2022/05/31        NaN                  NaN                  NaN
3  2022/05/01-2022/05/31        NaN                  NaN                  NaN
4                Deal ID  Deal Name     Origination Date        Maturity Date
5                    PEP       D251  2019-05-01 00:00:00  2023-03-13 00:00:00
6                     KO       D351  2020-10-02 00:00:00  2025-04-15 00:00:00
7                     MM       D451  2021-11-10 00:00:00  2026-12-01 00:00:00
```

Find and format run date file name - handles both `yyyy/mm/dd` and `mm/dd/yyyy`:

```
if df['Unnamed: 0'].str.match('^Run Date:.*\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d').any():
    fdate = df['Unnamed: 0'].str.extract('^Run Date:(\d{4}/\d\d)/\d\d').dropna().iat[0,0].replace('/','')
    fn = f'ExtensionReport{fdate}.csv'
    
elif df['Unnamed: 0'].str.match('^Run Date:.*\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}').any():
    my = df['Unnamed: 0'].str.extract('^Run Date:.*(\d\d)/\d\d/(\d{4})').dropna()
    fn = f'ExtensionReport{my.iat[0,1]+my.iat[0,0]}.csv'

fn

'ExtensionReport202205.csv'
```

Then get rid of everything above the headers:

```
df2 = df.dropna()
```

Then extract the headers and set the new column names from them:

```
df2.columns = df2.iloc[0].values
df2 = df2.iloc[1:,:]
```

Keep only processing deals.  Get rid of others - like In Queue:

```
if df2['Deal ID'].str.contains('Deal ID').any():
    df2 = df2.iloc[:df2['Deal ID'].str.contains('Deal ID').argmax()]
    
print(df2)

  Deal ID Deal Name     Origination Date        Maturity Date
5     PEP      D251  2019-05-01 00:00:00  2023-03-13 00:00:00
6      KO      D351  2020-10-02 00:00:00  2025-04-15 00:00:00
7      MM      D451  2021-11-10 00:00:00  2026-12-01 00:00:00
```

Then save to your named CSV:

```
df2.to_csv(fn, ...)
```

Comment: I made a mistake and now I am able to extract the date. But using this code I am also getting deals that are in the queue along with their headers(see the pic above)? Also  if date in this format 05/31/2022 then using the code how to get only 202205?

Comment: @cmpunk I updated my answer to address your new requirements